# Selenium Web Driver XPath/Element Issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

I am trying to get the total number of pages with reviews on Amazon Website:

https://www.amazon.com/Michel-Design-Works-Over-size-Triple-milled/product-reviews/B003LY94U4/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_prev_1?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1.

Here is my code below:

```
review_count_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-hook="cr-filter-info-review-rating-count"]')
print(f'review_count_text: {review_count_text.text}')
```

This gives output: `review_count_text: 165 total ratings, 49 with reviews`

```
num_pages = int(review_count_text.text.split()[-2])
print(f'num_pages: {num_pages}')
```

This throws `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'with'`

I tried using CSS selector and XPath locator strategy, but it didn't work:

```
num_pages = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-hook="cr-filter-info-review-rating-count"]').text.split()[-2])
```

```
num_pages = int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-hook="cr-filter-info-review-rating-count"]').text.split()[-2])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value at the negative index 2 (-2) is "**with**" which is of an `str` type.

Thus, you're trying to typecast a string to an integer.

```
int('with')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'with'
```

your target value (reviews, an integer) lies at the negative index 3 (-3).

Try this:

```
num_pages = int(review_count_text.text.split()[-3])
print(f'num_pages: {num_pages}')
```

Comment: Thank you Ajeet, I have figured that out but the main issue was the its the number of reviews its giving out, but not the number of pages.

Comment: @Srini_3100 The problem is that the first line in your question states, "I am trying to get the **total number of pages** with reviews on Amazon Website". This contradicts what you just said. You need to edit the question down to asking only a single question otherwise people are going to continue to be confused about what specifically you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current approach is that you are using the wrong index (and the wrong variable name and label). I've added some properly named variables, adjusted the indexes, and printed the output in the code below

```
review_count_text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@data-hook="cr-filter-info-review-rating-count"]')
print(f'review_count_text: {review_count_text.text}')
words = review_count_text.text.split()
num_ratings = int(words[0])
num_reviews = int(words[3])
print(f'num_ratings: {str(num_ratings)}')
print(f'num_reviews: {str(num_reviews)}')
```